# How does one write a regular expression that validates and corrects name strings?

Tags: regex

I'm using pcre regular expressions and I'm trying to clean up a list names for a mailing.

I'm trying to validate and enforce the following rules:

1. Name string start with an Upper Case initial followed by a period and space.
2. Last follow the space are no more than 18 characters and have no white space at the end.

I've included some examples here: [Example Name Strings](https://regex101.com/r/PDvRRi/1)

```
1. J. Doe
2. J Doe
3. J.  Doe
4. J  Doe   
5. J. Doe
```

1. number 1 is a valid name string
2. number 2 is missing the period after the first initial
3. number 3 has more than one space following the period.
4. number 4 has no period, two many spaces after the period and extra white space at the end.
5. number 5 has white space at the end of the name string

The first string meets all the criteria, but all other do not meet the criteria for one reason (no period, extra spaces, etc.) or another.

Is it possible for a regular expression to take these five name string and for it to return 5 identical valid name string like number 1.

I tried using a conditional regular expression,but found that to be a dead end.

Comment: We can of course write a regex which will validate a single letter initial followed by a last name.  But would this cover all your cases?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not sure I follow your question/comment.

Comment: My comment is saying what do you really want to validate?  Does a single initial followed by one name really cover all cases?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, I understand. Yes, it covers all cases but that still leave a lot of potential cases... This is where I find this difficult.

Comment: If it still leaves a lot of potential cases then it doesn't cover all cases, right?

Comment: I think you have to follow conditional regex because they are specially needed for violence-of-pattern detection & thus correction.

Comment: This problem is fraught with potential problems. Due to that, I wouldn't use regex for a specific solution. Just remove all non-alpha: Find `[^a-z]+` replace with nothing. then capitalize the first two letters, then insert a  `<dot><space>` after the first letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example cases, you can do `s/^\s*(\w)\w*\W+(\w+)/\1. \2/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ytW2eU/3)